# JSDT JQuery autocompletion is not working

Tags: jquery, eclipse-plugin, jsdt

I am using eclipse (Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)) and for Java Script code assist using 'SPKET' Ext JS 4 (jsb2) file. I tried a lot to make it work for JQuery but it is not working. Below steps i have done:

1. Downloaded and installed JSDT JQuery Integration software through eclipse. version is 1.7.0
2. using 'Window -> preferenes -> Spket -> JavaScript profile -> new -> mapped jQuery path.
   but its code assist is not working.
3. I created Java script project to test it but is not working, tried even with Dynamic web project but no luck.
   Same steps followed for Java Script using jsb2 file worked for me but Jquery is having issues. Spend 2 days doing this config but failed.

Answer (score 0):

Oh god..here mistake i was doing was, opening the .js file with the SPKET editor..this approach was not working, but yes the downloaded JQuery Integration works, to make it work I need to open the .js file with normal Java Script editor and not SPKET one. These are to different ways to configure for Jquery. So it is working now.